# Как в GridView Yii2 создать кастомный хедер в дополнение к основному?

Tags: yii2, header, gridview

Использую [GridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$headerRowOptions-detail) для вывода данных. Хочу в *thead* вместо одной строки иметь две. Можно ли это сделать, используя только возможности самого Yii2?

*Сразу оговорюсь, что вариант с модулем [yii2-grid](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid) рассматриваю как крайний.*

**Пример.** В выводимой таблице среди прочего есть две колонки с заголовками *"Ближайший показ"* и *"Время начала"*:

```
| Ближайшая дата показа | Время начала |
+-----------------------+--------------+
| 2015-10-23            | 19:30:00     |
| 2015-12-03            | 19:00:00     |
```

Я бы хотел добавить сверху над заголовком дополнительную строку, чтобы объединить колонки в группы по смыслу:

```
|    Ближайший показ    |
+------------+----------+
|    Дата    |  Начало  |
+------------+----------+
| 2015-10-23 | 19:30:00 |
| 2015-12-03 | 19:00:00 |
```

Как добавить такую строку в заголовок?

Comment: https://gitter.im/yiisoft/yii2/rus здесь спрашивали?

Comment: Чё-т глухо там.

Comment: а чем расширение то не подходит? обновлено 6 часов назад

Comment: При внимательном изучении выясняется, что многое работает из коробки. Не нужно плодить сущности и велосипеды. Вот я и подумал, а не делает ли Yii2 и это?

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный GridView не позволяет сделать дополнительный хедер. Чтобы не тащить тяжелое расширение можно чуть-чуть дополнить стандартный.

```
<?php

namespace common;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class GridView extends \yii\grid\GridView
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $myHeaderTitle = 'My default header title';

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $myHeaderRowOptions = [];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function renderTableHeader()
    {
        $customHeader = $this->renderCustomHeader();

        return $this->renderTableHeaderWithCustomHeader($customHeader);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function renderCustomHeader()
    {
        return Html::tag('th', $this->myHeaderTitle, [
            'colspan' => count($this->columns)
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    private function renderTableHeaderWithCustomHeader($customHeader)
    {
        $content = Html::tag('tr', $customHeader, $this->myHeaderRowOptions);
        $content = $content . parent::renderTableHeader();

        return "<thead>\n" . $content . "\n</thead>";
    }
}
```